# Android Firestore - Cache data once on first open and then update with snapshot?

Tags: java, android, caching, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to use snapshot listener with offline persistence to only read document that are different since app first open ?
For example i read all the recipes from /recipes/ collection on first app open and cache those recipes. Then when the user open the app again, with snapshot listener i check that the collection from server is unchanged. If there has been any write/delete/update in my database it will update my cached recipes but if there are none, i will not read my database again.

I need my app to work offline but stay updates when it needed without making thousand of reads on each open.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built in to Firestore for this. The reason is fairly straightforward: to determine if a document is modified, it'd have to read that document on the server.

The simplest way to add this yourself is by including information about when a document was modified in the document itself, and then only query for documents that were modified since the client last connected.

So it's a

1. Include a field `last_modified` in each document.
2. Ensure that each write operation includes that field, and set it to the server's timestamp.

   ```
   Map<String,Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
   updates.put("last_modified", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());

   docRef.update(updates)
   ```
3. Use server-side security rules to validate that this field is always set and correct.

   ```
   allow write: if request.resource.data.last_modified == request.time;
   ```
4. On the client query for only documents that were modified since the app last ran/read data.
5. Store the `last_read` timestamp in local storage of the app/device.

Comment: Such a great and easy solution ! 
All my write are reduce to one method so it will be a piece of cake.
Thanks you again !!